# How to use DBUnit with multiple databases / datasources in Spring

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test, dbunit

I am using *DBUnit* in my ***Spring***-based test case through extending class ***DBTestCase*** in my test class which runs using the '*SpringJUnit4ClassRunner*'.

Things work fine, however in my real-life application, tables are scattered across several *DB Schemas*, so I have several ***datasource*** beans defined in my *Spring Content XML*.

So when setting up *DBUnit*, we need to override method *newDatabaseTester* to provide it with a ***IDatabaseTester*** instance, while creating a '***DataSourceDatabaseTester***' bean takes only a **single** datasource in the constructor.

Does anyone know about the correct way to setup *DBUnit* in this case, or is there some sample project I can access which has implemented this ? Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at https://github.com/springtestdbunit/spring-test-dbunit#working-with-multiple-connections this library helps make simple configuration of DBUnit tests, and provides importing datasets to different dataSources.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this, and it appears the library only works if you provide XML files for the datasets; however instead I wish to query Datasets from another database (set of DBs) so each datasource will use another test schema to query the data. I am still looking at it thou, since right now I have no other option.

Comment: You can extend AbstractDataSetLoader and specify your implementation in @DbUnitConfiguration(dataSetLoader = YourDataSetLoader.class)

Comment: Also I appreiate the tip, but this is not so simple. AbstractDataSetLoader specifies a 'Resource' type parameter for the method to be overriden, and the abstract class checks if 'resource.exists()' so I can't even send the table names using this field. Instead, I'll need to modify the AbstractDataSetLoader, such a hassle.. The project is intended for Java 8 so it's not even compiling and I'll need an older version.